# Regex to match a string that contains substrings separated with dots

Tags: php, regex, validation

I need to get a value from an array using the dot notation. For example:

```
$arr = [
    'first' => [
        'second' => [
            'third' => 'hello'
        ]
    ]
];

$value = array_dot($arr, 'first.second.third'); // returns "hello"
```

So what I need to do is check if it's a valid string by which we could get a value from array.

Constraints:

- non-whitespace characters only
- contains at least one dot
- cannot start or end with a dot
- every dot must have a non-dot substring before and after it

Cases:

```
`value.inside.array` valid
`val-2.of.array` valid
`.var2.in.arr` invalid
`dot.notation.` invalid
`value. dot` invalid
`consecutive....dots` invalid
```

Comment: Should `consecutive....dots` be a valid path?

Comment: @mickmackusa no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[^.\s]\S*\.\S*[^.\s]$
```

Explanation:

```
^[^.\s]     Start with any non-dot and non-white character
\S*             Any non space characters
\.              Force at least one dot
\S*             Any non space characters
[^.\s]$    End with any non-dot and non-white character
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/KKCDqo/1).

Comment: Compare your output against mine in this demo: https://3v4l.org/hplm8

Comment: I got good answers from everyone, but somehow I like this one the most. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

A valid path, as far as I understand, will start with one or more non-dots, then it will be followed by one or more sequences of a dot then one or more non-dots (repeated as necessary to the end of the string).

Here is that logic in a regex pattern.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FU2MP))

```
$array = [
    "value.inside.array",
    "val-2.of.array",
    ".var2.in.arr",
    "dot.notation.",
    "value. dot",
    "consecutive....dots",
    "a.b.c.d.e.f"
];

var_export(
    preg_grep('~^[^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)+$~', $array)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'value.inside.array',
  1 => 'val-2.of.array',
  6 => 'a.b.c.d.e.f',
)
```

Or allow consecutive dots with this pattern: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qr2o1))

```
~^[^.\s]+\.\S*[^.\s]$~
```

Comment: avoiding consecutive dots makes perfect sense @mickmackusa!

Comment: I am not entirely sure.  An array key can be blank.  https://3v4l.org/uloop  This may be a subjective decision for the OP.

Comment: I am upvoting this answer as it correctly handles all edge cases (unlike the accepted solution).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `preg_match_all` here with an appropriate regex pattern.  We can first form a space-separated single string of all input terms using `implode()`.  Then, use a regex match all to fish out matching terms.

```
$array = ["value.inside.array", "val-2.of.array", ".var2.in.arr", "dot.notation.", "value. dot"];
$input = implode(" ", $array);
preg_match_all("/(?<!\S)[^.\s]\S*\.\S*[^.\s](?!\S)/", $input, $matches);
print_r($mstches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value.inside.array
    [1] => val-2.of.array
)
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
(?<!\S) assert that what precedes is either whitespace or the start of the string
[^.\s]  first character is non whitespace other than dot
\S*     match zero or more non whitespace characters
\.      match a dot
\S*     match zero or more non whitespace characters
[^.\s]  final character is non whitespace other than dot
(?!\S)  assert that what follows is either whitespace or the start of the string
```

Comment: To be, or not to be, `....` _that_ is the question.

Comment: @mickmackusa No, it's dot notation for arrays, commonly used in Laravel, like an accessor for keys inside a associative array.

Comment: @Amir if the answer is `No`, then the other two answers will not serve you in all cases and my answer is the only correct one on the page and you have accepted the wrong answer.